# Smart-table — how to come back to the last page selected

Tags: angularjs, smart-table

Case: the user has a table with multiple pages; he moves to page 4 and selects a row to view the details on another page, then he needs to come back to page 4.  How can make this?

I'm trying to set on window `localStorage` the value of current page and the object `ctrl.tableState().pagination` but it doesn't work.

Comment: I posted an answer to this on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29921339/smart-table-setting-page-from-code/32136115#32136115