# smart table pagination is not reset to first page on data source is updated

Tags: angularjs, smart-table

We have created report table using angular smart table.When a page is selected and updated the smart table data source. The page selection is still preserved. Not reset to first page.Please specify the method for reset the page selection to first page on data source updation

Comment: You could give the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29921339/smart-table-setting-page-from-code/32136115) a try upon data source is updated.